# How do I use `clojure.tools.macro/name-with-attributes`?

Tags: macros, clojure

I see what promises to be a nifty tool for anybody writing `defn`-like macros in the [clojure.tools.macro](https://github.com/clojure/tools.macro) library: the [`name-with-attributes`](http://clojure.github.io/tools.macro/#clojure.tools.macro/name-with-attributes) function.  The docstring says:

> To be used in macro definitions.
>      Handles optional docstrings and attribute maps for a name to be defined
>      in a list of macro arguments. If the first macro argument is a string,
>      it is added as a docstring to name and removed from the macro argument
>      list. If afterwards the first macro argument is a map, its entries are
>      added to the name's metadata map and the map is removed from the
>      macro argument list. The return value is a vector containing the name
>      with its extended metadata map and the list of unprocessed macro
>      arguments.

But I can't seem to find an example that uses this function anywhere.

So, how can I use this function to define, say, a `defn2` macro, which should be a clone of `clojure.core/defn` that contains all the same features, including:

- docstrings
- attribute maps
- preconditions
- multi-arities

Answer (score 6):

Here is `defn2`:

```
(require '[clojure.tools.macro :as ctm])

(defmacro defn2
  "A clone of `defn`."
  [symb & defn-args]
  (let [[symb body] (ctm/name-with-attributes symb defn-args)]
    `(defn ~symb ~@body)))
```

Looking at the metadata we can see that it gets properly attached:

```
(defn2 ^:private add
       "Docstring"
       ([] :foo)
       ([a b] {:pre [(= 1 1)]} (+ a b)))

(pprint (meta #'add))
```

...yields:

```
{:arglists ([] [a b]),
 :ns #<Namespace user>,
 :name add,
 :column 1,
 :private true,
 :doc "Docstring",
 :line 1,
 :file
 "/private/var/folders/30/v73zyld1359d7jb2xtlc_kjm0000gn/T/form-init8938188655190399857.clj"}
```

Using `defn2` above created an `add` function that works like so:

```
(add)     ; => :foo
(add 1 2) ; => 3
```